# Размер шрифта в Photoshop (16px = 8px ??)

Tags: photoshop

Все привет, подскажите пожалуйста. Вот мне заказчик говорит: *"хочу текст с размером в 16px"*. Я захожу в Photoshop (у меня macbook retina) и создаю документ: **1920x1080 (72ppi)** и, выбрав 16px размер шрифта, пишу текст. Но проблема в чем, в фотошопе **16px = 8px** на самом-то деле. А заказчик хочет 16px. И вот как мне решить эту проблему ?

Может я чего-то не знаю, потому что возникает вопрос о том, что в фотошопе мои "16" px растянут блок допустим на 16px в высоту, а при верстке текст растянет блок на 32px в высоту.

Comment: А и правда: заказчик точно хочет 16px, а не 16pt?

Comment: И да, фотошоп работает в 72dpi, а у заказчика небось Windows с 96dpi.